# Why don't we use the definite article before these examples?

Tags: definite-articles

'We need to look closely at ***business growth***, ***technological advancement***, ***economic trends***, and ***product development***.'

I would never say 'the business growth' or 'the technological advancement' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that, if you're talking about a particular instance of business growth, you would use the definite article (e.g., *the business growth we've been experiencing*).

Answer (score 2):

I think that here we are before a case of uncountable nouns, which don't need the definite article "*the*". But, not all of the ones you used are uncountable; "trend" is countable, for example, same goes for "development" that can be uncountable and countable.

Considering this, you might use the definite article (*"We need to look closely at the product development"* is acceptable).
So the difference stays here: you are not referring to a specific development, but rather to "general" elements, the ones you listed.

*About countable/uncountable:*
The definite article is used with *countable nouns*, usually. Same usually goes for the indefinite articles:

> - The car was parked there. `OR` I've seen a car.
>
> `And not:`
>
> - *Car was parked there `OR` *I've seen car.

You can use the definite article when you are referring to a specific "something" (uncountable) that is been previously referred to.

There is a good explanation [here](http://www.fortunecity.com/bally/durrus/153/gramch16.html).

Comment: i doubt if you answer Op's question.

Comment: Explain why not? He asked why he couldn't use the, I basically said "because they are uncountable nouns". Isn't it the answer he was looking for? I even gave him some reference material to cover all the related cases.

Comment: but your examples are too general for this case. as you said, uncountable nouns is not clear enough?

Comment: Plural nouns? I never mentioned plural nouns, what are you referring to?

Comment: It was my mistake.

Comment: I improved the answer.

Comment: i guess, it has something with the first and second noun in a phrase. in your example : "We need to look closely at the product development" talking about a special product or some special products which has/have development let us use "the". but when we don't talk about special product, "the" is dropped.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I said. :)