# on particular case of "the" usage

Tags: word-choice, definite-articles

I'm about to submit my thesis, and to do so I have to translate the title of the thesis into English. My main concern is about the use of *the*. My title reads as follows:

> On relations between sth1, sth2 and sth3.

Is it correct or should it be "*On **the** relations between...*"?

Comment: I'd use `the relationship(s)`

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: For a title, would you begin with "On"? Or simply, "The relationships between..."?

Comment: Are you talking about all of the relations (or relationships) that exist between the three things, or just some of them?

Comment: @w3d It is very common to begin scientific paper with "on". E.g., [On the Origin of Species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Origin_of_Species)

Comment: I think this is too localised. It's just a title, and it can include either or both of *"on"* and *"the"*, according to the writer's preference.

Comment: Go with "the" between "On" and "relations". Probably in your thesis you just describe _that_ relations.

Comment: @Luke: Good example, but I don't think *"On Origin of Species"* could possibly fly even if we weren't distracted by knowing the more famous one. On the other hand, OP's thesis could be titled *"On Relationships between A, B, and C"* - it doesn't *need* the word *"the"*.

Comment: @usage Here's what I was looking for. http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15208/24168 This explains the difference between "relation" and "relationship".

Comment: @Luke: Before I even go and look at that link, I'll say that so far as I'm concerned, "relations" and "relationships" can be considered equivalent *in OP's context*. ... okay, I've looked. In fact, they're probably *always* equivalent in the plural (except when *relations=kin* :)

Comment: @ FumbleFingers I would rather distinguish *relations* and *relationships* according to link provided by Luke.

Comment: @ThePhoton I consider some of the relations.

Comment: _Relation_ can mean a number of different things in different contexts; it would help immensely if you mentioned the scientific field the dissertation is in, and the type of relation(s) you're talking about -- social, historical, causal, correlational, military, diplomatic, etc, etc. I also see no particular reason to keep _sth1, sth2,_ and _sth3_ a secret. By the way, you want a comma after the next-to-last one in an series like that; otherwise it's potentially ambiguous.

Comment: @JohnLawler The field is mathematics. The aim of putting *sth*'s instead of triangles, squares and circles was to avoid distraction.

Comment: If you talk about "the relations between squares and circles", it implies you will describe all of the relations between them. If you just talk about "relations between squares and circles" or "certain relations between squares and circles" you can talk about just some of the relations, with no claim of completeness.

Comment: @ThePhoton I think that simply adding "certain" will be the most obvious an yet the best solution and it also resolves the ambiguity problem mentioned by JohnLawler. Thanks.

Comment: @usage: That should be "triangles, squares, and circles". **Two** commas; otherwise a parse like `Relationsbetween (triangles, And (squares, circles))` instead of `Relationsbetween (triangles, squares, circles)` can't be avoided.

Comment: No, "certain" does not resolve the ambiguity to which John Lawler was referring to. Infact that ambiguity is related to the problem named "serial commas".

Comment: I think ***certain*** _relations_ is a good idea (provided you use the commas correctly). It promises less and can deliver more. Plus you have a theme for the introduction, delimiting the scope of the study, which is very important. [My dissertation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/generics.html) was on English generic expressions, and when I realized I wasn't going to explain everything about them, I titled it _Studies in English Generics_.

Comment: @JohnLawler & Carlo_R. Yeah, you are both right. In my last comment I was thinking a bit ahead - that is about the problem with material covering which JohnLawler stated in his last comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: Using [the serial (or Oxford) comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) is the preferred style in the US; not having the comma is the preferred style in the UK; for other varieties of English I don't know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't we use the definite article before these examples?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24428/why-dont-we-use-the-definite-article-before-these-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both

> On relations between ...

and

> On the relations between ...

are equally good but with slightly different meanings. The first refers to some relations, not necessarily all, the second refers to all relations (possibly not the mathematical all, but at least all that are reasonably implied depending on context). The determiner 'the' really points to the exact set, and so all of them. Leaving the determiner out renders it a more vague reference.